# installing cvxopt on windows 10 using anaconda python 3.*

Tags: windows, python-3.x, anaconda, cvxopt

I've been trying to install cvxopt on Anaconda Python 3.x for a while now, reading past posts and I can't seem to make it work. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
pip install cvxopt --user
```

which gave me the following error:

```
Failed building wheel for cvxopt
```

Then I tried this:

```
conda install -c omnia cvxopt
```

output:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
- cvxopt
- python 3.5*
```

I installed mkl using this:

```
conda install mkl
```

which worked but trying out the previous commands still don't work.

I have installed multiple things in the past using the command prompt but my experience has told me to make sure I know and understand what I am installing because I wrecked my computer one time. So instead of trying things blindly, I would like to know if someone had a tipp.

Comment: Taking a look at the files, that channel does not have `cvxopt` for Python 3.5: https://anaconda.org/omnia/cvxopt/files Can you use Python 3.4?

Comment: when i look at the python version in my anaconda navigator it says python 3.5.I guess I'll try to access it from anaconda. It's weird that the 3.5 version isn't updated directly with all the packages though.. Thanks for the help !

Comment: You can create an environment that has Python 3.4 to use this package

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/cvxopt/cvxopt/issues/94) cvxopt does not support python 3.5+ due to compiler incompatibility.

Nevertheless, as stated in the comments, you can use anacodna to create a virtual environment and install it.

```
conda create --name py34 python=3.4 numpy
activate py34
conda install -c omnia cvxopt
```